# Mouseover/hover bug using Rotate (endless rotation) in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, transform, transition

I face such problem:

Mouseover on the right side, where the word `heree` is and you will get endless spinning (i use Firefox).

How to solve this?

```css
button{
  transition: 0.5s all;
  transform:none;
}

button:hover{
   transform:rotateY(360deg) scale(1.4);
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" >sumbittttttttttttttttttttt heree!</button>
```

P.S. If I remove `margin` parameter, then it works ok. But i want margin too!

Comment: perhaps in FF, add a class (which is the hover css) using jQuery on mouseenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because of `all` transition.

Set it only for the `transform` and I guess the issue is resolved here- in Firefox maybe the combination of `scaling` and `margin` on `hover` of the button is causing the issue.

```css
button{
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  transform:none;
}

button:hover{
   transform:rotateY(360deg) scale(1.4);
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" >sumbittttttttttttttttttttt heree!</button>
```

Let me know your feedback on this.Thanks!

Comment: Wow, maybe you'r right. ) However, it is bug maybe.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `button:hover + margin` is getting transitioned by `0.5s` as well as the transform. You just need to be a more specific with the transition : `transition: 0.5s transform;`

```css
button{
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  transform:none;
}

button:hover{
  transform:rotateY(360deg) scale(1.4);
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" >sumbittttttttttttttttttttt heree!</button>
```